# Rolling Window with custom lookback in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have timeseries data in a `Pandas` `DataFrame` and would like to know if it's possible to have a single call to `.resample()` or `.rolling()` to have a rolling window with a custom length, resampled at a different custom length. For example, every month I'd like a slice with a 1y lookback. Here is a function I wrote that does what I need:

```
def rolling_window(data, resample='1BM', lookback='252d'):
    dts = data.resample(resample).index
    for dt in dts:
        yield data.loc[dt-pd.Timedelta(lookback):dt]
```

It just seems like there should be a more elegant way but any combination of parameters to the above mentioned methods didn't give me what I need.

Comment: yes, see new rolling with time with windowing in 0.19.0 (coming soon); https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/13513

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. This looks like it allows time-aware window specification, but not to embed that with custom resampling. That's fine of course but would be nice if that was possible.